# Python - Error when calling a class function to analyze an array

Tags: python, class, numpy, scipy, ipython

I'm using a class that allows me to analyze an array of data that I have and returns it as an array.

Here is the portion of the class that i'm using.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

class MassFunction:

    def __init__(self, h=0.7, Omega_m=.27, sigma8=.809, n=0.95, rho_c=1.35972365653e11, delta_c=1.686):
        """
        @param h: hubble parameter.
        @param omega_m: current matter fraction of universe.
        @param sigma8: Value of variance of density field with spherical smoothing at 8 Mpc/h
        @param n: spectral scalar index for primordial power spectrum
        @param delta_c: amplitude of perturbation at collapse using linear theory.
        @param rho_c: critical density of universe in Msun/Mpc
        """
        self.h = h
        self.Omega_m = Omega_m
        self.n = n
        self.delta_c = delta_c
        self.rho_m = rho_c*Omega_m/self.h**2
        self.sigma8 = sigma8

    def NofM(self,masses, numbins, boxsize):
        """
        Produce mass function data for N(m). Fractional number density of halos in
        mass range (m,m+dm). Integrates to total number of halos/volume.
        @param masses: list of all masses in Msun/h
        @param numbins: number of bins to use in histogram
        @param boxsize: Size of box in MPc/h.
        @return: [x-axis in log10(mass), y-axis in log10(N(m)), xlabel, ylabel]
        """
        logmasses = np.log10(masses)
        hist, r_array = np.histogram(logmasses, numbins)
        dlogM = r_array[1]-r_array[0]
        x_array = r_array[1:] - .5*dlogM
        dM = 10.**r_array[1:]-10.**r_array[0:numbins] #Mass size of bins in non-log space.
        volume = np.float(boxsize**3) # in MPc^3
        return [x_array, np.log10(hist/volume/dM)]
```

The rest of the class is much longer, but using the other functions are not necessary in this case.

In my attempts of calling it, I imported it and tried to use it with the array of masses provided.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import MassFunction

# This is just the array of data 
halomass3 = halos3['GroupMass'] * 1e10 / 0.704 # in units of M_sol h^-1

MassFunction.MassFunction.NofM(halomass3,100, 75000 )
```

Im returned with this error `unbound method NofM() must be called with MassFunction instance as first argument (got ndarray instance instead)`

I'm not the most familiar with using classes, or calling classes, since this is my first time using them. Am I suppose to call the `__init__` and set up parameters or am I missing something more?

If I have left out any necessary information. Please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the class first.

```
MassFunction myinstance = MassFunction()
myinstance.NofM(halomass3,100, 75000)
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `NofM` doesn't depend on `self` so it can be defined as a *class method*.

Class methods are created with [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator to make them that doesn't require a first implicit argument `self`.

Update the method as follows:

```
@classmethod
def NofM(cls, masses, numbins, boxsize):
    ...
```

Class methods receives the class *(cls)* as implicit first argument, just like an instance method receives the instance *(self)*.

Now, you can call the class method as follows:

```
>>> MassFunction.MassFunction.NofM(halomass3, 100, 75000)
```